# Swift: Send data from a UITableView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a list of Cities in a TableView and want to pass the data from the cell in TableView to a UIViewController.  Now when I pass the data I also want to pass the Latitude and Longitude of those Cities to the UIViewController. Here is the TableViewController code.

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    let fruits = ["London", "Melbourne", "Singapore", "Brazil", "Germany", "Monza", "Dallas", "Auckland", "Brussels", "Shanghai", "Sepang", "Barcelona"]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

                (segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).detailItem = fruit
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = fruit
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
}
```

I can pass City but how would you pass the latitude of the longitude of the cities to the `UIViewController`. Here is the code for the `UIViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTemperatureLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var currentHumidityLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPrecipitationLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherIcon: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherSummary: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel?

    // Location coordinates
    let coordinate: (lat: Double, lon: Double) = (37.8267,-122.423)

    // TODO: Enter your API key here
    private let forecastAPIKey = ""

    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.description
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
        retrieveWeatherForecast()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func retrieveWeatherForecast() {
        let forecastService = ForecastService(APIKey: forecastAPIKey)
        forecastService.getForecast(coordinate.lat, lon: coordinate.lon) {
            (let currently) in

            if let currentWeather = currently {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    if let temperature = currentWeather.temperature {
                        self.currentTemperatureLabel?.text = "\(temperature)º"
                    }

                    if let humidity = currentWeather.humidity {
                        self.currentHumidityLabel?.text = "\(humidity)%"
                    }

                    if let precipitation = currentWeather.precipProbability {
                        self.currentPrecipitationLabel?.text = "\(precipitation)%"
                    }

                    if let icon = currentWeather.icon {
                        self.currentWeatherIcon?.image = icon
                    }

                    if let summary = currentWeather.summary {
                        self.currentWeatherSummary?.text = summary
                    }

                    self.toggleRefreshAnimation(false)

                }

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func refreshWeather() {
        toggleRefreshAnimation(true)
        retrieveWeatherForecast()
    }

    func toggleRefreshAnimation(on: Bool) {
        refreshButton?.hidden = on
        if on {
            activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
        } else {
            activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Master make direct use of the coordinate?  If not, the real question is why that particular model data is in Master.  Perhaps all Master needs to access or to pass is the city, and that Detail should retrieve the coordinate for the passed city from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property for the location to `ViewController`.

You can then pass the city's location in `MasterTableViewController` `prepareForSegue`, similar to how you're passing the city (detailItem) now.

**Update:**

To pass another parameter, you would add it to your `ViewController`

```
var coordinateItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}
```

and then pass it in `prepareForSegue`

```
(segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).coordinateItem = location
```

**Update 2:**

Yes, you can initialize an array of coordinates, and pass a latitude and longitude coordinate.

```
var locations : [[Double]] = [[51.50722, -0.12750], [-37.8136, 144.9631], ...]
```

In this case, your coordinateItem would be a `[Double]`.

You can access the two doubles by `coordinateItem[0]` and `coordinateItem[1]`

The general concept is the same, regardless of whether you're passing an array or a String.

Comment: How would you setup the longitude and latitude as an Array in the MasterTableViewController and that this matches the location in TableView. Plus, how would you pass this into the variable var coordinate: (lat: Double, lon: Double) = () ?

Comment: You make an array of locations (coordinates) that correspond to the same order as the city (fruit) array.  Then you can get `location[indexPath.row]` to know that city's latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hi Petah would this work override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
                let location = locations[indexPath.row]
                
                
                (segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).detailItem = fruit. How would you add this to the var coordinate in the UIViewController. Thanks a million for your help

Comment: Hi Christian, the issue I have is that this variable `var coordinate: (lat: Double, lon: Double) = (37.8267,-122.423)` is providing the coordinates for this statement in following function `func retrieveWeatherForecast() {
        let forecastService = ForecastService(APIKey: forecastAPIKey)
        forecastService.getForecast(coordinate.lat, lon: coordinate.lon) {
            (let currently) in` Would your solution still work? Thanks again for looking into this for me.

Comment: Just one more thing am I right in thinking this is how I declare coordinates as an array `let locations = ["51.50722; -0.12750","-37.8136, 144.9631","-23.5475000,-46.6361100","49.3297,8.57428","45.58005,9.27246"]` Again a million thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: Hi Petah you lost me there with `coordinateItem[0]` and `coordinateItem[1]` where would this go? Would I access this in the function on the ViewController `forecastService.getForecast(coordinate.lat, lon: coordinate.lon)`

Comment: Yes.  You can pass an array containing two doubles, and access each value.  `[0]` is the first `Double` element in the array, and `[1]` is the second array element.  The Swift ebook explains arrays, as well as how to pass data.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again! But when I pass this in I get an error `func retrieveWeatherForecast() {
        let forecastService = ForecastService(APIKey: forecastAPIKey)
        forecastService.getForecast(coordinateItem[0],coordinateItem[1],coordinateItem[2],coordinateItem[3],coordinateItem[4])` The error is  Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'Int'

Comment: We've changed from an abstract example (where the details weren't previously known) to a specific type, and "`coordinateItem` would be a `[Double]`".  If you don't understand the code you're trying to use, you're not doing yourself any favors.  You may want to consult a tutorial or the Swift book, to understand how to do this in general.  Once you have the basics down, then it's a simple matter to apply what you know in general to your specific case!

Comment: Please I beg you to help me as where ever Iook is not making sense.  I understand how to access the arrays but and I understand to some aspects of the tableView and I have even updated the textView.